# Orddict in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, key-value

From what I read,Orddict is simply a key value storage.

I came across terms like store,find,map to and realised there is something more to ordict just than storing values.

But in genral,when can one use **orddict**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An orddict is basically a list of `[{Key, Value}]` pairs, but where the elements are all sorted by the `Key` part. That makes lookups much faster compared to using a simple unsorted list of `[{Key, Value}]` pairs, because locating something over a sorted list can benefit from advanced search algorithms.

To be more specific, with a plain proplist you can't know the proximate location of any key relative to another, so there is no advantage to jumping midway into the list looking for a particular key versus simply iterating from the beginning to the end checking each key in sequence (in fact, hopping around instead of going head to tail incurs an overhead). With an orddict, however, you can check the middle key, determine if your target key is larger or smaller than the value there, and know whether to search before or after the middle key next, and hence drastically reduce the amount of search/compare performed. (Consider, for example, the [efficiency of binary search vs searching over random index windows](http://zxq9.com/archives/880), both of which drastically beat out iterative comparison.)

So it is really a question of efficiency, not a question of storage size or even semantics (most of the time you will be using these sort of structures internal to a module and the module's interface is all the outside world will see of it -- which somewhat mutes the effect/annoyance of the proplist and orddict interfaces being different).

Your discovery of common functional list operations over orddicts reflects two things: that they really are lists, and also that the interface provides ready-made methods to both leave the utility of orddicts as lists intact while permitting you to *use the [orddict](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/orddict.html) interface*. (Don't treat orddicts as raw lists -- you will eventually make yourself cry.)

There is a natural interface to unsorted lists in the [proplist](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) module. Proplists seem to be efficient enough that I don't notice any advantage on lists shorter than 15 items or so, but beyond that the overhead of orddicts is overcome by the efficiency of sorted search. Orddicts reign supreme up until around 100 items or so (Fred Herbert actually says its 75 in his book -- but I've not run the benchmark myself). Beyond that you will want to look for proper dictionary, tree, or indexed table structures -- and you *really* must benchmark your use case to discover which is the most efficient ("do I [write/update/delete/fetch/complex] query more than I [something else] over structures of [variable size] which needs to be [durable/ephemeral] and guaranteed robust across N node failures?" etc.).

In practical use I find myself using orddicts a lot for shortish sets of data, and when I start having efficiency problems it almost always means that I've not only outgrown orddicts but also outgrown other limitations built into my system (very often that I have a bottleneck introduced by not realizing I really need a *data service* and not just a sorted list of things). For example, if I have a room in a mud with players and items, the room will probably track lists of both as orddicts. If I have a list of inventory items in a business application that might be thousands of entries long its either in Postgres or an ETS table (or both, the ETS table being a "working copy" of queried data which exists only in the client's memory, and Postgres being the durable store somewhere more controlled).

Comment: i was going throuh this http://learnyousomeerlang.com/designing-a-concurrent-application#the-event-server .. the event server part is what put me in to confusion..the way orddict being used and PatternMatching being done is  little difficult to understand

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere He is using the monitor reference as the key, and the client info as the value in the orddict pairs as `{MonitorRef, ClientInfo}`. Using timeouts to make processes kill themselves to emulate timers (sort of like timebombs, really) when a client exits he can `orddict:find/2` or `orddict:erase/2` by matching a receive message on a client's monitor exit like `{'DOWN', Ref, process, _, _}`. This will to bind the symbol `Ref` to the key needed for the `orddict:erase/2` part in the main `evserv:loop/1` function's receive: [http://learnyousomeerlang.com/static/erlang/evserv.erl].

Comment: Bah, I messed up the link in the comment above. I was trying to link [to the evserv.erl file](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/static/erlang/evserv.erl).